# Пропала кнопка "в корзину" Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Тип цены стоит правильный, все работало пока не добавил больше товаров в компонент sale.bestellers

В чем может быть причина? https://prnt.sc/szv7pr

Comment: Может стоит количественный учет, и у товара  количество 0

Comment: Решил вопрос, кнопка сама работала и добавляла товар, переделал сообщение BX для вывода названия кнопки и все встало на свои места.